# Error calling a method from the main method involving string

Tags: java

I keep getting this error in my program where I am calling the method `getValWords` and the error say the following **"The method getValidWords(String) in the type anothertry is not applicable for the arguments (File)".**

This is a sample of my code.

```
    File file = new File (args[0]);
    List<String> words = getValidWords(file);  
    Collections.sort(words);

    System.out.println(words.toString());

    }

public static String[] getValidWords(String s) {
    s = s.replaceAll("[0-9]\\p{L}+", " "); // Removes any word starting with a number
    s = s.replaceAll("\\s+", " "); // trims extra whitespace "    " into " "
    return s.split(" ");
}
```

Comment: And what do you think that error means? A File and a String are different things.

Comment: You can't assign `String[]` to `List<String>`

Comment: You forgot a step. See: [How do I create a Java string from the contents of a file?](//stackoverflow.com/q/326390)

Answer (score 0):

You must get file content first and convert to string then you call this method.